# Adding a WCF service on Sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, wcf

Does SharePoint 365 (SharePoint Online) support package (wsp) with custom WCF webservice ?

Because I've a wsp package created for on-premise SharePoint, and I need to make it work for SharePoint 365. This package doesn't use any third party library, but add a WCF service (svc extension) in an ISAPI folder.

I've googled but didn't found any specific information for SP365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online doesn't support Farm Deployments.

Solution to your problem is to host your WCF service some where say Azure. Then use Client Side Object model to query information from SharePoint.

Comment: The original request was to push data (document + metadata) in SP. The existing web service (SP2010) were not enough to upload document with managed metadata, so I had to create my own webservice so my application could upload document to sharepoint. Do you think that now this is possible with CSOM ?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847935/upload-a-document-to-a-sharepoint-list-from-client-side-object-model